# SSIS - Load CSV files located in SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

I need solution for a task I am working on.
I need to load multiple CSV files into sql server table.
ALL CSV have the same structure.

The source of the CSV are in a sql server table.

SOURCE_TABLE structure.

```
ID -> Primary Key - IDENTITY
Path -> Varchar(100)
```

Source_Table data

```
ID  Path
1   c:\1.csv
2   c:\2.csv
3   c:\x.csv
.
.
.
.
```

Target_Table Structure   (No Primary key in this table).

```
ID - INT     -> Foreign key from Source Table. (This is NOT primary key)
Date - Today Date&Time
1    --> All 1 through 5 are headers from CSV file. basically they are the contents from the csv file
2
3
4
5
```

The target table has
TARGET_TABLE

```
ID      DateTime   <-and the columns from CSV file ->
1       Today      x  y  z  -> contents of c:\1.csv
1       Today      1  2  3  -> contents of c:\1.csv
1       Today      4  5  6  -> contents of c:\1.csv
1       Today      x  y  z  -> contents of c:\1.csv
2       today      sdf sdf sdf  -> contents of c:\2.csv
2       today      sdf sdf sdf  -> contents of c:\2.csv
2       today      sdf sdf sdf  -> contents of c:\2.csv
2       today      sdf sdf sdf  -> contents of c:\2.csv
2       today      sdf sdf sdf  -> contents of c:\2.csv
3       today      sdfs  sds  sdf  -> contents of c:\x.csv
3       today      sdfs  sds  sdf  -> contents of c:\x.csv
3       today      sdfs  sds  sdf  -> contents of c:\x.csv
3       today      sdfs  sds  sdf  -> contents of c:\x.csv
3       today      sdfs  sds  sdf  -> contents of c:\x.csv
```

and so on ...

The ID on TARGE_TABLE must match the ID on the SOURCE TABLE

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the `ID` value for the target table coming from the file name of the CSV file, or is it data **in** the CSV file?  If you post the actual table definition for `Target_Table` and the top few rows of one of your CSV files, that would be helpful.

Comment: The ID from the SOURCE_TABLE is IDENTITY. The ID from the TARGET_TABLE is the ID from the SOURCE_TABLE. The ID in the TARGET_TABLE is NOT primary Key.

Comment: Again, please post the actual table definition for `Target_Table` and a few sample rows from your CSV files.  Remember - we're not **nearly** as familiar with what you're doing as you are.  See [ask] and [mcve] for some additional guidance on how to post effective questions.

Comment: @brian - i just updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

An overview of how to accomplish this is below.  Given that your question indicates that all the CSV files share the same definition, this example goes by the following assumption, and that the target table contains columns with the appropriate corresponding data types as well.

- Create three variables.  The first one having an int data type, which can be called `ID`.  Make the second variable a string data type and name it `FilePath` or something similar.  An object data type will be used for the third variable and it can be named `FileList`.
- Create a Flat File connection manager using the definition of any source file.  Since it will be used to load multiple files, the file path (connection string) will need to be dynamic.  To do this, go to the Flat File connection manager properties (press `F4`), find the `Expressions` field and press the ellipsis next to it.  On the window that appears choose the `ConnectionString` property and select the `FilePath` string variable that was created.  If you haven't already, also create an OLE DB connection manager to the database where the target table is located.
- Add an Execute SQL Task on the Control Flow.  For the SQL statement enter a `SELECT` command that returns the ID and path columns from the source table in this order.  On the task editor choose the `Full Result Set` option for the `ResultType` property.  On the Result Set pane enter 0 in the Result Name column an add the object variable (`FileList`) in the Variable Name field.
- Next add a Foreach Loop after the Execute SQL Task and connect this to it.  Choose the `Foreach ADO Enumerator` option for the enumerator field.  In the ADO Object Source Variable field select the `FileList` object variable.  On the Variable Mappings tab, add the int variable (`ID`) at index 0 and string `FilePath` Variable at index 1.  This will map columns of the row from the current iteration of the object variables to the other variables.  Although this is using the same order as the `SELECT` statement, i.e. ID followed by path column, it can be switched if you want.
- Create a Data Flow Task inside the Foreach Loop.  Add a Flat File Source with the Flat File connection manager that was previously defined.  Next add a Derived Column transformation.  On this, add two additional output columns.  The first output column will be the ID, and set the int `ID` variable as the expression with an int (`DT_I4`) data type.  For datetime column of the target table in your example, I'm assuming you want the date and time that the file was imported.  For this, add another output column on the Derived Column Transformation with the `GETDATE()` expression to return the date and time of the import.  This will have the `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` data type which corresponds to the SQL Server datetime date type.  If this data type differs, see the mapping table in the [SSIS data type documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-2017).
- After the Derived Column add an OLE DB Destination.  Set the target table as the destination, and I'd recommend using the Fast Load option, which operates as a BULK INSERT operation.  On the Mappings pane, match the ID derived column to the ID column of the destination table, the datetime derived column to the column of the destination table it correlates to, and the remaining output columns of the Flat File Source to the appropriate columns of the destination table.

**Helpful links**

- [Looping Through a Result Set with the ForEach Loop](http://blog.pragmaticworks.com/looping-through-a-result-set-with-the-foreach-loop)
- [Using SSIS to Loop Over Result Set and Dynamically Generate Output Files](https://coldlogics.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/using-ssis-to-dynamically-create-data-files-from-a-full-result-set/)